# High CPU usage when using some Prisma types with React Hook Form

Tags: typescript, prisma, react-hook-form

I'm working on a form using both `react-hook-form` and `prisma`.

I have a very simple model named `Company`

When using `npx prisma generate`, all related types are created, including `CompanyCreateInput`

Now here's the catch, the following code will work just fine:

```
import { Prisma, Company } from '@prisma/client'  

const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
} = useForm<Company>();
```

But this one will result in an instant 100% CPU usage by the VSCode ts server.

```
import { Prisma, Company } from '@prisma/client'  

const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
} = useForm<Prisma.CompanyCreateInput>();
```

Has anyone faced this before? This completely cripples the developer experience

Comment: For what it's worth, I have this same thing - it'll chew up a whole CPU, tyepescript stops working (Says everything is any) and my intellisense breaks too. It just says "loading" - Problem is I couldn't recreate it with a CodeSandbox to create an issue.